# Setting the Locale and Collations of AWS RDS Aurora Postgres

Tags: postgresql, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

When a Postgres 15 database(cluster) is created in AWS RDS Aurora Postgres the locale and collations of the database(s) are defaulted to `en_US.UTF8`.

I need to set the **locale** and the **collations** to other values :

`--locale=fr_CA.UTF8 --lc-collate=fr-CA-x-icu --lc-ctype=fr-CA-x-icu`

This works fine when I create my own postgres database locally ... but in AWS RDS Aurora, I can't find where to set that in the UI or the CLI or my terraform scripts (terraform-aws-rds-aurora)

Can this be done for AWS RDS Aurora Postgres ?

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure if that can be done, but make sure to check this: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/rds_cluster_parameter_group.